# $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nx_k$ diverges to infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series

suppose $\{x_n\}_n$ is a sequence of positive real numbers such that $x_n\rightarrow 0$ an $n\to\infty$.

> Does there exists any such sequence such that $$\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k$$ diverges to infinity as $n\to\infty$?

Anyone can check that $\sum_n \frac{1}{n}$ is not such sequence. Actually, does there really such sequence exists?

Comment: Since $x_n\rightarrow0$, there is some $N$ so that for all $n>N$, $x_n<1$. How does this help you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a sequence $(x_n)_n$ is bounded by a constant $M$ (such as a convergent sequence) then 
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k\leq \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}M=M,$$
that is the sequence $(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k)_n$ is bounded as well (it does not diverge to infinity).

Comment: thanks, and sorry that my question was not well written at first.

Answer (score 3):

[Stolz-Cesàro](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) gives,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} x_{k}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{(n+1)-n}=0$$

Comment: thanks for the link.

Comment: You're welcome, hope it's helpful. Please let me know if anything needs further clarification.